# Combining 2 ansi text replace scripts into one script. Both scripts work fine independently

Tags: powershell

I have 2 functioning scripts I'm using to convert some ANSI text files into HTML for viewing on a webpage. I would like to join the 2 into 1.

This is the first script I run.
SCORES.PS1

```
$scoretext = 'score.ans'
$scorehtml =  'C:\xampp\htdocs\gamedata\score.shtml'
Set-Location -Path C:\mystic\doors\LORD
(Get-Content $scoretext) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace ' ', '&nbsp;' `
       -replace '(\x1B)', '' `
       -replace '(\[)', '' `
       -replace '0;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' `
       -replace '0;31m', '</font><font color="DarkRed">' `
       -replace '0;32m', '</font><font color="Green">' `
       -replace '0;33m', '</font><font color="Orange">' `
       -replace '0;34m', '</font><font color="DarkBlue">' `
       -replace '0;35m', '</font><font color="DarkMagenta">' `
       -replace '0;36m', '</font><font color="DarkCyan">' `
       -replace '0;37m', '</font><font color="Gray">' `
       -replace '1;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' `
       -replace '1;31m', '</font><font color="Red">' `
       -replace '1;32m', '</font><font color="LightGreen">' `
       -replace '1;33m', '</font><font color="Yellow">' `
       -replace '1;34m', '</font><font color="Blue">' `
       -replace '1;35m', '</font><font color="Magenta">' `
       -replace '1;36m', '</font><font color="Cyan">' `
       -replace '1;37m', '</font><font color="White">' `
       -replace '-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-', '<font color="LightGreen">-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-</font>' `
       -replace '&nbsp;</font><font color="White">On', '</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font>' `
       -replace '\S+$','$&<br>' `
       -replace 'Alive<br>','Alive&nbsp;<br>' 
    } | Set-Content $scorehtml
```

Then once that is done, I have something else figure out which users are online and dynamically generate a ps1 file to add tags to the score list...

SHOWONLINE.PS1

```
Get-Content score.shtml | ForEach-Object {
$line = $_

$a = "The Illest"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}
$a = "Johnboy"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}

$line
} | Set-Content score.on
```

I Tried doing this but its skips the Johnboy line...

```
Get-Content score.shtml | ForEach-Object {
$line = $_

$line = $_ -replace ' ', '&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '0;31m', '</font><font color="DarkRed">' -replace '0;32m', '</font><font color="Green">' -replace '0;33m', '</font><font color="Orange">' -replace '0;34m', '</font><font color="DarkBlue">' -replace '0;35m', '</font><font color="DarkMagenta">' -replace '0;36m', '</font><font color="DarkCyan">' -replace '0;37m', '</font><font color="Gray">' -replace '1;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '1;31m', '</font><font color="Red">' -replace '1;32m', '</font><font color="LightGreen">' -replace '1;33m', '</font><font color="Yellow">' -replace '1;34m', '</font><font color="Blue">' -replace '1;35m', '</font><font color="Magenta">' -replace '1;36m', '</font><font color="Cyan">' -replace '1;37m', '</font><font color="White">' -replace '-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-', '<font color="LightGreen">-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-</font>' -replace '&nbsp;</font><font color="White">On', '</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font>' -replace '\S+$','$&<br>' -replace 'Alive<br>','Alive&nbsp;<br>'

$a = "The Illest"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}
$a = "Johnboy"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}

$line
} | Set-Content score.on
```

The I MOVE /Y score.on overwriting score.shtml for the final file..

If I try and condense the **FIRST** script into a single $line = $_ -replace ......... and merge it into the second(updated w/example), with a new $line = $_ -replace,  it ends up skipping the johnboy line completely.. I dont think its the replace fields i think I am not understanding it correctly.. I will still have to convert this into something useable as I cannot just make one big script and use it, like i said the second is created by another file, but if I can see it working I can adapt it for my uses.

EDIT - Cleaned out cmd esc chars from generated ps script examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the example I tried by simply prepending each identified line with the main replacement string used for all other lines.., then since the replacements happen in order i was able to make the final edits to data that didnt initially exist ;P

```
Get-Content score.ans | ForEach-Object {
$line = $_

$line = $_ -replace ' ', '&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '0;31m', '</font><font color="DarkRed">' -replace '0;32m', '</font><font color="Green">' -replace '0;33m', '</font><font color="Orange">' -replace '0;34m', '</font><font color="DarkBlue">' -replace '0;35m', '</font><font color="DarkMagenta">' -replace '0;36m', '</font><font color="DarkCyan">' -replace '0;37m', '</font><font color="Gray">' -replace '1;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '1;31m', '</font><font color="Red">' -replace '1;32m', '</font><font color="LightGreen">' -replace '1;33m', '</font><font color="Yellow">' -replace '1;34m', '</font><font color="Blue">' -replace '1;35m', '</font><font color="Magenta">' -replace '1;36m', '</font><font color="Cyan">' -replace '1;37m', '</font><font color="White">' -replace '-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-', '<font color="LightGreen">-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-</font>' -replace '&nbsp;</font><font color="White">On', '</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font>' -replace '\S+$','$&<br>' -replace 'Alive<br>','Alive&nbsp;<br>'

$a = "The Illest"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace ' ', '&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '0;31m', '</font><font color="DarkRed">' -replace '0;32m', '</font><font color="Green">' -replace '0;33m', '</font><font color="Orange">' -replace '0;34m', '</font><font color="DarkBlue">' -replace '0;35m', '</font><font color="DarkMagenta">' -replace '0;36m', '</font><font color="DarkCyan">' -replace '0;37m', '</font><font color="Gray">' -replace '1;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '1;31m', '</font><font color="Red">' -replace '1;32m', '</font><font color="LightGreen">' -replace '1;33m', '</font><font color="Yellow">' -replace '1;34m', '</font><font color="Blue">' -replace '1;35m', '</font><font color="Magenta">' -replace '1;36m', '</font><font color="Cyan">' -replace '1;37m', '</font><font color="White">' -replace '&nbsp;</font><font color="White">On', '</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font>' -replace '\S+$','$&<br>' -replace 'Alive<br>','Alive&nbsp;<br>' -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}

$a = "Johnboy"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
$line = $_ -replace ' ', '&nbsp;' -replace '(\x1B)', '' -replace '(\[)', '' -replace '0;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '0;31m', '</font><font color="DarkRed">' -replace '0;32m', '</font><font color="Green">' -replace '0;33m', '</font><font color="Orange">' -replace '0;34m', '</font><font color="DarkBlue">' -replace '0;35m', '</font><font color="DarkMagenta">' -replace '0;36m', '</font><font color="DarkCyan">' -replace '0;37m', '</font><font color="Gray">' -replace '1;30m', '</font><font color="Black">' -replace '1;31m', '</font><font color="Red">' -replace '1;32m', '</font><font color="LightGreen">' -replace '1;33m', '</font><font color="Yellow">' -replace '1;34m', '</font><font color="Blue">' -replace '1;35m', '</font><font color="Magenta">' -replace '1;36m', '</font><font color="Cyan">' -replace '1;37m', '</font><font color="White">' -replace '&nbsp;</font><font color="White">On', '</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font>' -replace '\S+$','$&<br>' -replace 'Alive<br>','Alive&nbsp;<br>' -replace 'Alive&nbsp;<br>', 'Alive&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>' -replace 'Dead&nbsp;<br>', 'Dead&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font class="blink" color="Red">On</font><br>'
}

$line
} | Set-Content score.shtml
```